# Unable to understand the recursive function in C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I am unable to understand the execution of the code given below. When we call the function `DisplayRev()` it is going to check the length of argument, then it is going to separate the first index, and then function is executed again with remaining string. The last statements are not going to execute till string length is greater than zero.

What is the functionality of  `Console.Write(str[0]);` and when it is going to execute?

```
class RevStr {  
  // Display a string backward.  
   public void DisplayRev(string str) {    
     if (str.Length > 0)      
       DisplayRev(str.Substring(1, str.Length - 1));    
     else      
       return;   

     Console.Write(str[0]);  
   } 
} 

class RevStrDemo {  
  static void Main() {    
    string s = "this is a test";    

    RevStr rsOb = new RevStr();    

    Console.WriteLine("Original string:"+s);                            
    Console.Write("Reversed string: ");    

    rsOb.DisplayRev(s);    

    Console.WriteLine();  
  } 
}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint and step through your code. You should easily be able to see what's happening and where.

Comment: in addition to sab669 comment. press `F11` to debug step by step. so you can see what happens each line

Comment: If you use Visual Studio, you have break points, and then Debug tools such as Watch, Locals, and Call Stack. If you open them all you will see everything what happens in code

Comment: If all else fails, just run it and see what appears on your Console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to follow really. Suppose you call the function like this:

```
DisplayRev("Hello");
```

The length of the string is 5 (which is greater than 0), so it calls itself, passing in a new string. This new string is the original string minus the first letter, so the call becomes:

```
DisplayRev("ello");
```

Then it does it again, following the same process:

```
DisplayRev("llo");
```

Then:

```
DisplayRev("lo");
```

Then:

```
DisplayRev("o");
```

Now comes the magic part. It starts to write the first letter in the string:

So `DisplayRev("o");` writes `o`. Then the function returns and the `DisplayRev("lo");` writes the first letter `l`. So no your screen shows `ol`. Then the function returns and the `DisplayRev("llo");` writes the first letter `l` and the screen shows `oll`, then the function returns and the `DisplayRev("ello");` prints the first letter, `e`. Now the screen shows `olle`. Finally, the original call prints the first letter, 'H' and the screen shows `olleH`.

By the way, this is good for learning how recursion works, but there are easier ways to reverse a string, such as:

```
string reverseValue = new string(original.Select((c, index) => new { c, index })
                                         .OrderByDescending(x => x.index)
                                         .Select(x => x.c)
                                         .ToArray());
```

Comment: How can this part work `(c, index) => new { c, index }`? I have tried something similar such as `Select(x => x.....)` but I could not find anything related to index.

Comment: @Celdor -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much dear i got your point  but can you explain the code you mentioned  above .........

Comment: @KazimHussain -  `original` contains the string. The first `Select` is telling it to select the character and put it in `c` and select the index and store it in `index` and the result of the `Select` will be put into a new string. So we are ordering by descending by the index, which means it'll start at the end of the string and iterate through each character. It selects the character and puts it into an array. That array is then used to initialize a new instance of a string. That's basically it!

Comment: @Icemanind I realised I should have check the documents in the first place but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good idea to look at a simple example: `DisplayRev("CAT")`.

This first does `DisplayRev("AT")` and *then* it prints `C`. So printing `C` will be the **last** thing the method does.

In the same way, `DisplayRev("AT")` first does `DisplayRev("T")` and *then* it prints `A` (but this happens before `C` is printed).

`DisplayRev("T")`  first does `DisplayRev("")` and *then* it prints `T` (but this happens before `A` or `C` are printed).

`DisplayRev("")` doesn't print anything because the length if the string is zero.

Therefore we see that the method will print the letters in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

As the function calls itself recursively, each letter will wait for the rest of the string to be processed before it writes out, which leads to the string being written in reverse.

The length of 0 is the termination condition which causes all of the previous values to be able to complete their execution in reverse order.

Think of it like the the stack, or if you're new to programming in general, like a stack of plates in a rack. You bring them out of the kitchen in a stack (the original order of the letters) and then one at a time you place them onto the rack. When it comes time to use the plates, the bottom one, despite originally being first, has to wait for everything on top of it to be used first, so the order is reversed.

The best thing to do is to step through in a trace and you should be able to understand the problem.

Answer (score -4):

If you pass it a string like "ABCDEF" it will write "FEDCBA" on the console.

Comment: I'm not sure that he was looking for what it does, but how it works (I didn't downvote, but this isn't an answer either way).

Comment: I gave the answer because I thought it would show them that although the A is processed first, it isn't printed until after it returns from the recursive call. Sort of a hint how it's working.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he knew that's what it did... he's just trying to understand how it works....

Comment: there is a comment upside that method. `// Display a string backward.` :-)